# Substract epoch time from datatime.datatime.now

Tags: python, datetime, subtraction

I was asked to get the value of a key from a JSON on a particular website and subtract that value with `.now` (it's an expiration date).

I'm doing it using a `requests.get` as well as a `json.load`. My problem is: The value that I'm getting is epoch time and `datetime.datetime.now` is not.

What's the easiest way to (`datetime.datetime.now - my key(epoch value)`)? See values in screenshot below. I've tried converting from epoch to "human date" then do a subtraction with it but nope.

[image: see both values here datetime.datetime.now on top and epoch from json on the bottom]

**EDIT**: This may **not** be a **duplicate** because it asks about processing a **timestamp** and wants number of seconds **between** that timestamp and now.

Comment: This may **not** be a **duplicate** because it asks about processing a **timestamp** and wants number of seconds **between** that timestamp and now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did say easiest. When a timestamp is involved think of the [arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

```
>>> time_string = '2017-08-14 11:52:09.145000'
>>> import arrow
>>> time_diff = arrow.now()-arrow.get(time_string)
>>> time_diff.total_seconds()
17604.346025
```

Comment: Thanks! this is indeed way easier! fixed my problem1

Comment: Good! You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Use the python [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) module to convert your epoch value to a date and then just subtract them like:

```
diff = datetime.now() - my_date
```

You could also use the [relativedelta](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) class if you want the output as a number of days, months, years, etc.